# how to select the content of each json array?

Tags: php, json

I'm having trouble selecting only the values i need from json data :

```
foreach ($users as $row) {  
 $usersDepartement = json_decode($row["departement"]);
 var_dump($usersDepartement);
}
```

I get this

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(0) "" } } array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(10) "33-gironde" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(9) "40-landes" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(17) "47-lot et garonne" } [3]=> object(stdClass)#9 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(11) "64-pyrenees" } } array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(10) "33-gironde" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#10 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(9) "40-landes" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#11 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(17) "47-lot et garonne" } }
```

How in the world can i get all the values from one of the resulting arrays ?
I tried this : `var_dump($usersDepartement[0});`
But I get all the first values from each arrays not all the values from the first array :

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(0) "" } object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(10) "33-gironde" } object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["userDepartement"]=> string(10) "33-gironde" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possibilities. But what you tried is logical. You create an array of objects. In this example 4 to be exact. You access the first object when you access the first entry of the array:

```
$usersDepartement[0]
```

The second object would be:

```
$usersDepartement[1]
```

The easiest way to do this and understand it is to loop all objects and get the value you want. So full code would be:

```
$valuesYouWant = []    
foreach ($users as $row) {  
     $usersDepartement = json_decode($row["departement"]);
        foreach ($usersDepartement as $element) {
          $valuesYouWant[] = $element->userDepartement;
        }
    }
     var_dump($valuesYouWant);
```